# Detecting USB mass storage device connections using python

Tags: python, usb

How can I monitor connections usb mass storage device connections in python? I found a few options but I am stymied at one point or the other in both these options.

- First is udev (pyudev) which has an excellent system to monitor device connections. Unfortunately, can't get a filter up because I don't know which subsystem, DEVTYPE etc. must be specified.
- Second, dbus. But HAL seems to be deprecated. Also ran into some problems regarding .service files and stuff. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273153/error-in-this-sample-hal-dbus-program) here. I feel it's occuring because HAL is deprecated but if it's something else and there's a work around please let me know!

  Have scourged the world wide web and haven't found the solution to the above roadblocks. Please help!

Comment: There is a [tutorial here](http://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/python-detection-of-usb-storage-device/) that might help..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at gudev

there is a simple example

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1695571.html

basically, it look like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glib
import gudev
import pynotify
import sys


def callback(client, action, device, user_data):
device_vendor = device.get_property("ID_VENDOR_ENC")
device_model = device.get_property("ID_MODEL_ENC")
if action == "add":
    n = pynotify.Notification("USB Device Added", "%s %s is now connected to your system" % (device_vendor,device_model))
    n.show()
elif action == "remove":
    n = pynotify.Notification("USB Device Removed", "%s %s has been disconnected from your system" %
(device_vendor, device_model))
n.show()


if not pynotify.init("USB Device Notifier"):
    sys.exit("Couldn't connect to the notification daemon!")

client = gudev.Client(["usb/usb_device"])
client.connect("uevent", callback, None)

loop = glib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```